# condition inside child doesn't updated screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

First, I separated all my widgets for cleaner code structure. I prepared a condition wherein I can change my layout based on its value. If true, show this, if false show this.

I debugPrint the value of the boolean and it shows that the value is being updated whenever the gesture is detected. But the screen doesn't update when it happens.

the condition is set on my homeWidget file.

```
AnimatedContainer(
                duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                child: isScrolled
                    ? Container(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Flexible(
                              flex: 2,
                              child: StoriesWidget(),
                            ),
                            Flexible(
                              flex: 5,
                              child: PostWidget(),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    : Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Flexible(flex: 3, child: ProfileWidget()),
                            Flexible(flex: 5, child: StoriesWidget()),
                            Flexible(
                              flex: 10,
                              child: Container(
                                width: double.infinity,
                                height: double.infinity,
                                child: PostWidget(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ))));
```

The updating of the value Happens inside a separate Widget called postWidget

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => profileAction(),

  profileAction() {
    debugPrint("$isScrolled");
    setState(() {
      isScrolled = true;
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you please provide where the AnimatedContainer is coming from?
is the child of GestureDetector ?

Comment: AnimatedContainer is from my homeWidget.dart file.  GestureDetector is from postWidget.dart file